# How do I extract the matching part of a regex on Solaris

Tags: solaris, grep, regex

GNU's grep has the option `--only-matching`, which prints just the matching region of a regular expression.  I'm on a Solaris 5.10 box without any GNU tools installed, and I'm trying to achieve the same thing.  Example:

```
grep -Eo "[0-9]+ ms" *.log
```

Is there a sed or awk expression that can do the same thing?

Comment: It would help if you showed what a line from the file looks like and what exactly you're trying to extract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n 's/.*[^0-9]\([0-9]\+ ms\).*/\1/p' *.log
```

A possible refinement for versions of `sed` which support this type of alternation:

```
sed -n 's/\(^\|.*[^0-9]\)\([0-9]\+ ms\).*/\2/p' *.log
```

In OS X, I had to use extended regular expressions because I couldn't get basic enhanced regular expressions to work (this would work in GNU `sed`, too, if you change `-E` to `-r`, but the basic enhanced version works there, too):

```
sed -En 's/(^|.*[^0-9])([0-9]+ ms).*/\2/p' *.log
```

These two latter examples work even if the sequence you're searching for appears at the beginning of the line with no leading characters.

Comment: Thanks.  Changing the + to * works.  Solaris' sed doesn't support extended regular expressions.

Comment: @brianegge: The equivalent to `+` when it isn't available is, in this case, `[0-9][0-9]*`

Comment: @Arrow A possibly better anchor that is more general is a non-digit instead of a space. I've added that to my answer. Thanks for pointing out the flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Try using /usr/sfw/bin/ggrep

> /usr/sfw/bin/ggrep -V
>   grep (GNU grep) 2.5

Copyright 1988, 1992-1999, 2000, 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

>

Comment: Nope.  The sfw packages aren't installed, and I don't have access to install them.  The only directory I can write to is /tmp, and it would be easier to copy the files back to a machine with gnu grep on it than to copy grep to /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

Solaris 5.10 includes bash 3.00, which has a modern regex engine.  The follow command works, though it's quite a bit more verbose than a grep or sed solution.

```
cat *.log | while read line; 
do 
  if [[ $line =~ "([0-9]+) ms" ]]; then 
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; 
  fi;
done
```

(Formatted on multiple lines for readability)

Comment: Bash regex handling changed for version 3.2. You should not quote the pattern because it will be treated as a literal string instead of a regex. Since unquoted patterns also work in Bash 3.0 and 3.1, you should use them there, too, for forward compatibility. Further, I recommend that the pattern be stored in a variable and the variable should be used on the right side of `=~`. For example: `pattern='([0-9]+) ms'; if [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]`